# Saving existing node doesn't update automatic alias

Tags: path-aliases

I have a node with pattern `/route/[node:title]`. Whenever I save a new node with automatic alias checked it saves perfectly.

Whenever I edit an existing node with Generate automatic alias checked it doesn't update the URL to the new title but instead keeps the old one. When I go back to editing I see that Generate automatic alias is unchecked all of a sudden and an alias is in place(The old title).

I'm using Pathauto and Pathauto persist but can't seem to find the problem, even when disabling and uninstalling Pathauto persist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked your settings at "admin/config/search/path/settings"?
There you can config what to do with your alias, when an entity is updated.